# Javascript Array.some() and Array.every() equivalent for Set?

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

In JavaScript, is there an equivalent of `Array.some()` and `Array.every()` for the `Set` built-in object?

Comment: Nah, if you want those use `Array.from(set).some()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the only built-in methods on `Set.prototype` [are](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```
Set.prototype​.add()
Set.prototype​.clear()
Set.prototype​.delete()
Set.prototype​.entries()
Set.prototype​.for​Each()
Set.prototype​.has()
Set.prototype​.values()
Set.prototype​[@@iterator]()
```

It'd probably be easiest to just convert the set to an array, and then use the array methods.

```js
const set1 = new Set([1, 2]);
const set2 = new Set([-1, 2]);

const allPositive = set => [...set].every(num => num > 0);
console.log(
  allPositive(set1),
  allPositive(set2)
);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not natively available on the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) prototype, but if you found yourself needing this frequently, you could easily extent Set to add it.

```js
class extendedSet extends Set{
  every(f){
    return Array.prototype.every.call([...this], f)
  }
  some(f){
    return Array.prototype.some.call([...this], f)
  }
}

let a_set = new extendedSet([1, 2, 3, 4]);

console.log(a_set.every(n => n < 2))
console.log(a_set.some(n => n < 2))

// still works as a Set
console.log(a_set.has(4))
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers suggest first converting the set to an array and then using some array method. This is completely unnecessary and even sub-optimal.

You can use a `for` loop on the set instance itself, iterate over it, find an element that matches a given condition, then break the loop:

```js
function some(set, predicate) {
  for (const item of set)
    if (predicate(item))
      return true;

  return false;
}
```

```
function every(set, predicate) {
  for (const item of set)
    if (!predicate(item))
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

```
const set = new Set([ 42, 17, -1, 8.3 ]);

every(set, (item) => typeof item === "number"); // true
every(set, (item) => item > 0); // false

some(set, (item) => item < 0); // true
some(set, (item) => item === 0); // false
```

Comment: And as a bonus, the some and every functions in this answer will work for any iterable collection (arrays, TypedArrays, strings, Maps where the items will be [key,value] pairs, etc.) in addition to Sets.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Methods is the documentation for the list avaiable methods for the `Set`

> **Methods:**
>
> Set.prototype​.add()
>
> Set.prototype​.clear()
>
> Set.prototype​.delete()
>
> Set.prototype​.entries()
>
> Set.prototype​.for​Each()
>
> Set.prototype​.has()
>
> Set.prototype​.values()
>
> Set.prototype​@@iterator

In your context you could do something like below:

```
 Array.from(set).some() or Array.from(set).every()
```

For more info regarding [Array vs Set](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/es6-set-vs-array-what-and-when-efc055655e1a)