# Check numerical array if it includes values from numerical set

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array with type of PlayerTextInfo.

Array of type PlayerTextInfo = [{playerType:1, text:""}]

```
allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo = [
0: {playerType: 1, text: "some text A"}
1: {playerType: 1, text: "some text B"}
2: {playerType: 1, text: "some text C"}
3: {playerType: 2, text: "some text D"}
4: {playerType: 1, text: "some text E"}
5: {playerType: 1, text: "some text F"}
6: {playerType: 2, text: "some text G"}
7: {playerType: 2, text: "some text H"}
]
```

I want to get all the `playerType`s and create a new numerical Set with no duplicate values.

```
const validPlayerTypes= new Set([]);

allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo.forEach((x) =>validPlayerTypes
.add(x.playerType));

// validPlayerTypes ==> {1,2}
```

If there is at least one object in the allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo  with playerType which is not included in the Set then I want to return false.

For example: Last three values have playerType = 3 which is not included in validPlayerTypes Set. All objects of allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo must have playerType either 1 or 2.

```
allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo = [
0: {playerType: 1, text: "some text A"}
1: {playerType: 1, text: "some text B"}
2: {playerType: 1, text: "some text C"}
3: {playerType: 2, text: "some text D"}
4: {playerType: 1, text: "some text E"}
5: {playerType: 3, text: "some text F"}
6: {playerType: 3, text: "some text G"}
7: {playerType: 3, text: "some text H"}
]
```

I have tried `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.some`.

**UPDATE**

I have a set of buttons and when the user clicks them, a popup is shown.
The user can edit each Player and configure the Type and Text.
User can add dynamically more objects of {Type, Text} into the player array.

Code example below:

```
const allPlayers: Players[] = 
    [ 0:{name:"Player1",
     configuration: [0:{playerType: 1, text:"sometext"}, 1:{playerType: 2, text:"some text - on type 2"}]}, .... same for rest of players];

// Create an array with only the configurations
const allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo = [];
allPlayers.forEach((x)=>allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo.push(x.configuration));

// Create a Set which will have no duplicates type ids
const validPlayerTypes= new Set<number>([]);
allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo.forEach((x)=>validPlayerTypes.add(x.playerType));

// Check if there is a player with configuration that does not include all the ids of the validPlayerTypes
const hasAllPlayerConfigurationsCorrectly = allPlayers.forEach((player) => player.configuration.forEach((config) => validPlayerTypes.has(config.playerType)));
```

This shoould return false if it finds at least one playerType value that is not included in validPlayerTypes. Am I right?

What I want exactly is after updating a player to check whenever the rest of the player configurations are the same.

All player configurations must have same Type ids.

For example:
If player 1 has configured Type 1 and 2, then all the rest must have configured Type 1 and 2. Else the SAVE button must be disabled.

Bellow is a demo image:

[image]
How can I do the above?

Comment: _What_ have you tried with `every`/`some`? Give a [mre].

Comment: Well `every` would be the logical one, but like mentioned above you have not shown what you tried with `every` so not easy to say what you did wrong.  mmm, but saying that `some` might be better for performance.. :)

Comment: What makes playerType: 3 suddenly appear - when can you create the set and why did it not work? You would need to do [...set].every: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56094884/javascript-array-some-and-array-every-equivalent-for-set

Comment: When copying data into a question, please get the data using `console.log(JSON.stringify(allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo, null, 2))` instead of copying directly from the console's representation of an array, which adds unnecessary data (indexes) and leaves out necessary syntax (commas).

Comment: I have updated the description with more details, code and an image. Please if you want more details let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try **every** :

```js
let allPlayerTypesAndTextInfoValidValues = [
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text A" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text B" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text C" },
  { playerType: 2, text: "some text D" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text E" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text F" },
  { playerType: 2, text: "some text G" },
  { playerType: 2, text: "some text H" }
];
let allPlayerTypesAndTextInfo = [
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text A" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text B" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text C" },
  { playerType: 2, text: "some text D" },
  { playerType: 1, text: "some text E" },
  { playerType: 3, text: "some text F" },
  { playerType: 3, text: "some text G" },
  { playerType: 3, text: "some text H" }
];
let requiredValues = new Set(allPlayerTypesAndTextInfoValidValues.map(p => p.playerType));
let containOnlyValidValues = allPlayerTypesAndTextInfo.every(p => requiredValues.has(p.playerType));
console.log(containOnlyValidValues);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's straight forward. Not sure what issue you are fetching with Array.some() method.

```
 allPLayerTypesAndTextInfo.some((item) => {
    return !validPlayerTypes.has(item.playerType);
 });
```

If this solution doesn't work. Please let me know on which section you are having issue.

Comment: I have managed to make it work using both every and has. What I did is compare the size and if every element exist in both =>                                                                                       
 const isEqualSets = (plValid: Set<number>, plInfo: Set<number>) =>
      plValid.size === plInfo.size &&
      [...plValid].every((x) => plInfo.has(x));